# How to make a teleporter in unity3d?

Tags: unity, collision-detection

For my game, I need to teleport player (`GameObject`) to a position (`Vector3`) whenever it touches a cube with this script. I tried using this:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Teleporter : MonoBehaviour
{

    public GameObject player;
    public Vector3 target;

    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        player.transform.Translate(target);
    }
}
```

and passing player and position in the inspector:
[image: image of inspector configuration of my object]
but it does nothing, when player touches a cube with this script. Please tell me how to fix this, or a completely new idea to teleport the player, that works. Thanks

Comment: Have you confirmed whether your method is being called at all? Show us the inspector configuration of your player object and the teleporter object.

Comment: Added the inspector configuration as an image. The script is connected at the bottom

Comment: This script will always move the player, no matter what object actually collides with the teleporter. You might want to add a check in your `OnCollisionEnter` method which confirms that the `collision.gameObject` your receive is actually the player.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`transform.Translate()` takes a *relative* offset, ie. "How far do you want me to move from where I am?"

If you pass (0, 0, 0), as in your current inspector settings, you're saying "don't move anywhere at all" — so it's obeying, exactly as you asked.

Instead, you might have meant to write:

```
player.transform.position = target;
```

...to reposition the player to the point (0, 0, 0) in world space.